# How to deal with merged objects/resources in a web app and in a RESTful API?

Tags: language-agnostic, web-applications, rest

I have a web app that has lots of pages with a URL of the form /object_type/object_id/ which show this objects details. I also have a RESTful API, returning a JSON/XML representation of my objects (under /api/object_type/object_id/ ). (My objects are Laws and Bills, but I guess this question is rather generic).

From time to time, I discover that 2 or more of my objects are actually duplicates, and describe the same object in the real world. Lets say they were /Bill/111/ and /Bill/222/ . Behind the scenes I merge the 2 objects, leaving 1 object (lets say /Bill/111/ ) with all the information, and the other "empty" with just a reference to the other one.

My question is, **how should I indicate the merge in the web app and in the API?** I don't want /Bill/222/ to return a 404, because I might have external links pointing to it, and I don't want them broken. Should I use a 301 Moved Permanently? Should I return a normal page (with status 200) explaining that this resource was detected as duplicate with a link to the merged one? How should I deal with this in the API? for example, should I list 222 in the Bills index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would use a 301 for this case and would stop including 222 in the list.  The only reason for the 301 is incase some client had bookmarked the URL.

Answer (score 1):

@Darrel Miller:

> I think I would use a 301 for this case and would stop including 222 in the list. The only reason for the 301 is incase some client had bookmarked the URL.

I would only add that the system should accept links to /Bill/222 and /Bill/111 as equivalent, i.e. given a user editing /Joe/999 indicating that /Bill/222 is a friend of Joe's:

```
PUT /Joe/999
Content-Type: vnd.xxx+xml

<name is-friend-of="/Bill/222">Joe</name>
```

This should be semantically identical to befriending /Bill/111, and indeed after issuing the above PUT, I wouldn't be surprised that when I GET it back that I see the link changed to 111.

Comment: The only problem with keeping the two URLs around is that as per the resolution of Issue 14 Range http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/issues.html#httpRange-14  there should only be one URL that returns a 200 for single resource.  There can be multiple URIs for a resource, but the others should return a redirect if dereferenced.